# Invoke expression from variable in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to store certain expressions/methods in variable and execute them.
For example to create a new directory, i am trying following.

```
def createDir = 'new File("new").mkdir()'
createDir
```

But it does not create a 'new' folder. If i just use **new File("new").mkdir()**, it works

In other words i am looking for invoke-expression(powershell) equivalent in groovy

Answer (score 2):

You normally use a [closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) for that.

```
def createDir = { new File('new').mkdir() }
// call it with
createDir()
```

You can even parametrize it

```
def createDir = { new File(it).mkdir() }
// call it with
createDir('new')
```

The variable `it` is the implicit parameter of a closure, see the docs I linked above.

If you want to dynamically construct the expression then you can use [Eval](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html#integ-eval)

```
import groovy.util.Eval

assert Eval.me('33*3') == 99

def createDir = 'new File("new").mkdir()'
Eval.me(createDir)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to directly execute a function from it's string representation you can use the `evaluate()` function which will run the code found in a string (or file). **You should exercise caution with this and never execute a string provided by/containing input from a user**. Here's an example:

```
def function = "println 'This came from a string!'"
evaluate(function)
```

That being said, I think you would be better going with a solution similar to the one proposed by Leonard Brünings in his answer, as it is much safer and less prone to errors.